# How to iterate through a dictionary inside of a list, which is a value of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have been having a hard time to understand how should I approach that problem.

I have a dictionary, that contains lists for each key value.

Each list carries n numbers of dictionaries.

Inside of those dictionaries, there is a value that I need to sum up, for each key value of the main dictionary.

I do have no idea how to iterate through a dictionary which is inside of a list, that is a value from a greater dictionary.

I'll provide the main code below. Could someone help me to understand how to approach the problem?

Input, where groups is a dict and 'Hydrofilm...' is one of the key values':

```
groups['Hydrofilm 10cm x 15cm VP Adh Film Dress']
```

Output, which is a list of dictionary related with that key value:

```
[{'bnf_code': '20030100236',
  'items': 1,
  'practice': 'P81069',
  'bnf_name': 'Hydrofilm 10cm x 15cm VP Adh Film Dress',
  'nic': 10.6,
  'act_cost': 9.83,
  'quantity': 20},
 {'bnf_code': '20030100236',
  'items': 1,
  'practice': 'P81100',
  'bnf_name': 'Hydrofilm 10cm x 15cm VP Adh Film Dress',
  'nic': 10.6,
  'act_cost': 9.81,
  'quantity': 20},
 {'bnf_code': '20030100236',
  'items': 1,
  'practice': 'J81043',
  'bnf_name': 'Hydrofilm 10cm x 15cm VP Adh Film Dress',
  'nic': 5.3,
  'act_cost': 4.92,
  'quantity': 10},
 {'bnf_code': '20030100236',
  'items': 1,
  'practice': 'J81056',
  'bnf_name': 'Hydrofilm 10cm x 15cm VP Adh Film Dress',
  'nic': 5.3,
  'act_cost': 4.92,
  'quantity': 10},
 {'bnf_code': '20030100236',
  'items': 1,
  'practice': 'J81057',
  'bnf_name': 'Hydrofilm 10cm x 15cm VP Adh Film Dress',
  'nic': 5.3,
  'act_cost': 4.92,
  'quantity': 10}]
```

The key that needs to be sum is the 'items'

Expected results:

```
sum_list = [1,1,1,1,1]
```

Comment: For the input, please [edit] you question and show a sample of what might be in the list associated with `groups['Hydrofilm 10cm x 15cm VP Adh Film Dress']` key.

Answer (score 0):

Assign that list of dicts to `elements`.
Then we want:

```
>>> [element['items']  for element in elements]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum_list = [element['items'] for element in dataSet if element['bnf_code'] == 'Hydrofilm 10cm x 15cm VP Adh Film Dress'`